# How can I recover httpd.conf file?

Tags: centos, centos6

I am using CENTos 6.6. I accidentally removed the httpd.conf file. Now, apache is running but if I restart it, It will crash. How can I recover httpd.conf file?

Comment: restore backup?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the original file back with a simple reinstall of the `httpd` package - `yum reinstall httpd`. This will not recover any modifications you've made to the file, however. You'll have to redo those modifications manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a single file from the rpm without reinstall of httpd

First get the path within the rpm

```
rpm -qlp httpd-...rpm | grep httpd.conf
```

after that you can get the single file with

```
rpm2cpio httpd-...rpm | cpio -ivd ./etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't make any modifications to it then the other answers are better/quicker.

**If** you have `mod_info` enabled and accessible, you can get the configuration by accessing `/server-info?config` and extracting the relevant parts from it.
But be aware of the [limitations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html#limitations) of this.